# Haunted house in Gdansk - what is the exact address?

Tags: sightseeing, locate-this, gdansk

I am going to go to Poland, Gdansk and just thought to find something abandoned and interesting. So I googled it and found that there is an abandoned manor, but I failed to find any coordinates of this place. So maybe someone can help me find it?

[image]
The story is here: [The Haunted Manor in Gdansk, Northern Poland](http://www.slavorum.org/the-haunted-manor-in-gdansk-northern-poland/).

And more concrete information with address is here [O nie-masońskiej kamienicy przy ulicy Sobótki](http://ibedeker.pl/obiekty/o-nie-masonskiej-kamienicy-przy-ulicy-sobotki/#axzz2InEoNaf6); Google translate: [About a non-Masonic house on Sobotki Street](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fibedeker.pl%2Fobiekty%2Fo-nie-masonskiej-kamienicy-przy-ulicy-sobotki%2F%23axzz2InEoNaf6&edit-text=)

Maybe someone knows where it this on Google Maps? I tried a couple of adresses, but no luck.

Comment: Excellent edit, I removed my downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's here

https://www.google.pl/maps/@54.3735056,18.6068758,18z

https://www.google.pl/maps/place/Sob%C3%B3tki+20,+Gda%C5%84sk/@54.3734114,18.6096,268a,35y,270h,39.44t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x46fd74915a85241b:0xf0501d2d6aefd76d!8m2!3d54.374743!4d18.6094149

but even though it says it's abandoned, it doesn't mean you can legally explore it, usually in places like that, there are security cameras or a guard person around who can make problems if he finds you there